# findOneAndUpdate work in mongo shell, but doesn't update with node-mongodb?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, node-mongodb-native

I have this function, which search for a document with a given ID (mID), check if another field exist (u) and if not, add the given id (uID).

The code doesn't throw any error, but doesn't update the document either, however, building the query myself from the same field (the two `console.log`) and using them in the mongo shell does work.

The result of the query when used with node-mongodb-native is `{ ok: 1, nModified: 0, n: 0 }`

```
'use strict';

const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient,
    async = require('async'),
    uuid = require('node-uuid'),
    winston = require('winston'),
    logger = new (winston.Logger)({transports: [new winston.transports.Console()]});

let Link = {};

function link(mId, base, uId, callback) {
    let filter = {'mId': mId},
        update = {'$set': {}};

    filter[base] = {'$exists': false};
    update['$set'][base] = uId;

    logger.info('link update', {filter: filter, update: update});
    console.log('db.Link.findOne(' + require('util').inspect(filter) + ');');
    console.log('db.Link.findOneAndUpdate(' + require('util').inspect(filter) + ', ' + require('util').inspect(update) + ', {upsert: false, new: true});');
    Link.collection('link')
    .findOneAndUpdate(
        filter,
        update,
        {
            upsert: false,
            returnOriginal: false
        }
    ).then((result) => {
        logger.info('link update ok', {result: result});
        callback();
    }).catch((error) => {
        logger.error('link update error', {error: error});
        callback(new Error(4299));
    });
}

async.waterfall([
    (callback) => {
        MongoClient.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1/Link').then((db) => {
            logger.info('Connected to Link');
            Link = db;
            callback(null);
        }).catch((error) => {
            logger.error('init Link', {error: error});
            callback(error);
        });
    },
    (callback) => {
        let mId = uuid.v4();
        logger.info('create');

        Link.collection('Link')
        .insertOne({'mId': mId})
        .then((error) => {
            logger.info('create ok')
            callback(null, mId);
        }).catch((error) => {
            logger.error('create error', {error: error});
            callback(new Error(4299));
        });
    },
    (mId, callback) => {
        link(mId, 'link', uuid.v4(), callback);
    }
], (error) => {
    if(error) {
        logger.error('End', {error, error});
    }
    logger.info('End');
    Link.close();
});
```

I also tried with `update` and `updateOne` functions, but same result: command work, not the code.

Can anybody explain why a command that work from the shell couldn't work when made from the driver, and why Mongo report it found a document, but don't update it?

node v6.9.1, node-mongodb-native v2.2.11

Edit:

Base document:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("58332c30224fe3273c7b1ba6"),
    "mId" : "37286c83-7d81-484d-b62a-310f690cac97"
}
```

Updated document:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("58332c30224fe3273c7b1ba6"),
    "mId" : "37286c83-7d81-484d-b62a-310f690cac97",
    "test" : "f7bb9386-eedd-43fe-890a-348cb3a97ed3"
}
```

Logger output:

```
info: Connected to Link
info: create
info: create ok
info: link update mId=f8ba93da-3b6d-43f7-9f90-4e345ba04131, $exists=false, link=f882d44d-60a3-4701-b5df-ba493c3b249b
db.Link.findOne({ mId: 'f8ba93da-3b6d-43f7-9f90-4e345ba04131',
  link: { '$exists': false } });
db.Link.findOneAndUpdate({ mId: 'f8ba93da-3b6d-43f7-9f90-4e345ba04131',
  link: { '$exists': false } }, { '$set': { link: 'f882d44d-60a3-4701-b5df-ba493c3b249b' } }, {upsert: false, new: true});
info: link update ok updatedExisting=false, n=0, value=null, ok=1
info: End
```

The `init` function connect to mongoDB, the `create` function insert into it a new document with a random `mId` that is passed to the `link` function.
The uId is also created randomly and is also a UUID.

While it should be equivalent, the command printed in the console logs:

```
db.Link.findOneAndUpdate({ mId: 'f8ba93da-3b6d-43f7-9f90-4e345ba04131',
```

link: { '$exists': false } }, { '$set': { link: 'f882d44d-60a3-4701-b5df-ba493c3b249b' } }, {upsert: false});

do update the document

Comment: You don't show the document you're trying to update, but my guess is that `mId` and `uId` are numbers in the document, but are strings in your code. If so you need to convert using code like `{mId: parseInt(mId, 10)}`.

Comment: @JohnnyHK: No, I only save UUID (generated from `node-uuid`), so everything are strings

Comment: @DrakaSAN - show us, what is logger output. We do now know, what parameters are, probalby there is some mistake.

Comment: Could you simplify this down to a more minimal, but complete example that reproduces the problem with the example document that you show? There's too much irrelevant stuff going on here with the query building.

Comment: @JohnnyHK: Done, reduced the code and removed my custom dependencies, the function itself is 26 lines, but I ve included a complete example in 72 with init and insert.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, **you're using wrong Collection Name**

When you insert one you use uppercase **Link**

```
Link.collection('Link') <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
    .insertOne({'mId': mId})
```

When you try to update you are using lowercase **link**

```
Link.collection('link') <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
    .findOneAndUpdate(
```

Comment: 100pts is a just punishment for not seeing such a little mistake earlier, good job to you.